# String concatenation utility in C++11

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, c++14

I published a concatenation utility lastly and I feel it could be very good help for many people, but before I promote it, I would like to polish the details as much as I can. So I'll like to ask you to review this less than 300 lines of code.

```
#ifndef THEYPSILON_CONCAT
#define THEYPSILON_CONCAT

#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>

namespace theypsilon {

    template <typename CharT>
    struct separator_t {
        const CharT* sep;
        constexpr explicit separator_t(const CharT* s) noexcept: sep{s} {} 
    };

    template <typename CharT>
    constexpr separator_t<CharT> separator(const CharT* s) {
        return separator_t<CharT>(s);
    }

    namespace sep {
        constexpr char none [] = "";
        constexpr char space[] = " ";
        constexpr char endl [] = "\n";
        constexpr char coma [] = ", ";
        constexpr char plus [] = " + ";
    };

    namespace { // type helpers and traits
        template<typename T>
        struct has_const_iterator {
        private:
            typedef char                      yes;
            typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

            template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::const_iterator*);
            template<typename C> static no  test(...);
        public:
            static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
            typedef T type;
        };

        template <typename T>
        struct has_begin_end {
            template<typename C> static char (&f(typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator (C::*)() const>(&C::begin)),
            typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value, void>::type*))[1];

            template<typename C> static char (&f(...))[2];

            template<typename C> static char (&g(typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<typename C::const_iterator (C::*)() const>(&C::end)),
            typename C::const_iterator(C::*)() const>::value, void>::type*))[1];

            template<typename C> static char (&g(...))[2];

            static bool const beg_value = sizeof(f<T>(0)) == 1;
            static bool const end_value = sizeof(g<T>(0)) == 1;
        };

        template<typename T, typename CharT>
        constexpr bool is_writable_stream() {
            return  std::is_same<T, std::basic_ostringstream<CharT>>::value || 
                    std::is_same<T, std::basic_stringstream <CharT>>::value ||
                    std::is_same<T, std::basic_ostream<CharT>>::value;
        }

        template<typename T, typename CharT = char> 
        constexpr bool is_stringstream() {
            return  std::is_same<T, std::basic_istringstream<CharT>>::value || 
                    std::is_same<T, std::basic_ostringstream<CharT>>::value ||
                    std::is_same<T, std::basic_stringstream <CharT>>::value;
        }

        template<typename T> 
        constexpr bool is_char_type() {
            return  std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, char    >::value || 
                    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, wchar_t >::value || 
                    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, char16_t>::value || 
                    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type ,char32_t>::value;
        }

        template<typename T, typename CharT = char>
        constexpr bool is_c_str() { 
            return  std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, CharT const *>::value ||
                    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, CharT       *>::value;
        }

        template<typename T> 
        constexpr bool is_char_sequence() {
            return  is_c_str<T,     char>() ||
                    is_c_str<T,  wchar_t>() ||
                    is_c_str<T, char16_t>() ||
                    is_c_str<T, char32_t>();
        }

        template<typename T> 
        constexpr bool is_container() {
            return (has_const_iterator<T>::value && 
                    has_begin_end<T>::beg_value  && 
                    has_begin_end<T>::end_value  &&
                    !std::is_same<T, std::string>::value &&
                    !is_stringstream<T>()) 
            || (std::is_array<T>::value && !is_char_sequence<T*>());
        }

        template <typename T>
        constexpr bool is_string() {
            return  std::is_same<T,std::string   >::value ||
                    std::is_same<T,std::wstring  >::value ||
                    std::is_same<T,std::u16string>::value ||
                    std::is_same<T,std::u32string>::value;
        }

        template <typename T>
        constexpr bool is_basic_type() {
            return std::is_scalar<T>::value || is_string<T>();
        }

        template <typename T, template <typename...> class Template>
        struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

        template <template <typename...> class Template, typename... Args>
        struct is_specialization_of<Template<Args...>, Template> : std::true_type {};

        template <typename T>
        constexpr bool is_modifier() {
            return  !is_container    <T>() && !is_stringstream    <T>() && 
                    !is_char_sequence<T>() && !is_basic_type<T>() &&
                    !std::is_array<T>::value && 
                    !is_specialization_of<T, std::tuple>::value;
        }
    }

    namespace { // concat_intern

        template <typename CharT, char head, char... tail>
        std::basic_string<CharT> get_separator() { return {head, tail...}; }

        template <typename W, typename S>
        void separate(W& writter, const S* separator) { 
            if (separator) writter << separator;
        }

        template <typename W, typename S>
        void separate(W& writter, const S& separator) { 
            writter << separator;
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W>
        std::basic_string<CharT> concat_to_string(const W& writter) {
            return writter.good() ? writter.str() : std::basic_string<CharT>();
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
        void concat_intern_write(W&, const S&, bool, const T&);

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            typename std::enable_if<is_char_sequence<T*>(),
        void>::type concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const T* v) {
            if (v) writter << v;
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            typename std::enable_if<
                (!is_container<T>() && !is_stringstream<T>() && !is_char_sequence<T>()) || is_modifier<T>(),
        void>::type concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& v) {
            writter << v;
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            typename std::enable_if<is_stringstream<T>(),
        void>::type concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& v) {
            if (v.good()) writter << concat_to_string<CharT>(v);
            else writter.setstate(v.rdstate());
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            typename std::enable_if<is_container<T>(),
        void>::type concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& container) {
            auto it = std::begin(container), et = std::end(container);
            while(it != et) {
                auto element = *it;
                it++;
                concat_intern_write<CharT>(writter, separator, it != et, element);
            }
        }

        template<unsigned N, unsigned Last>
        struct tuple_printer {
            template<typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            static void print(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& v) {
                concat_intern_write<CharT>(writter, separator, true, std::get<N>(v));
                tuple_printer<N + 1, Last>::template print<CharT>(writter, separator, v);
            }
        };

        template<unsigned N>
        struct tuple_printer<N, N> {
            template<typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
            static void print(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& v) {
                concat_intern_write<CharT>(writter, separator, false, std::get<N>(v));
            }
        };

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename... Args>
        void concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const std::tuple<Args...>& v) {
            tuple_printer<0, sizeof...(Args) - 1>::template print<CharT>(writter, separator, v);
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T, typename... Args>
        void concat_intern_recursion(W& writter, const S& separator, const T& head, const Args&... tail) {
            concat_intern_write<CharT>(writter, separator, true, head);
            concat_intern_recursion<CharT>(writter, separator, tail...);
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename W, typename S, typename T>
        inline void concat_intern_write(W& writter, const S& separator, bool b, const T& v) {
            concat_intern_recursion<CharT>(writter, separator, v);
            if (b && !is_modifier<T>()) separate(writter, separator);
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename S, typename T, typename... Args,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<is_writable_stream<T, CharT>() == true, T>::type>
        std::basic_string<CharT> concat_intern(const S& separator, T& writter, const Args&... seq) {
            concat_intern_recursion<CharT>(writter, separator, seq...);
            return concat_to_string<CharT>(writter);
        }

        template <typename CharT, typename S, typename... Args>
        std::basic_string<CharT> concat_intern(const S& separator, const Args&... seq) {
            std::basic_ostringstream<CharT> writter;
            return concat_intern<CharT>(separator, writter, seq...);
        }
    }

    template <typename CharT = char, typename... Args>
    std::basic_string<CharT> concat(const separator_t<CharT>& sep, Args&&... seq) {
        return concat_intern<CharT>(
            sep.sep, 
            std::forward<Args>(seq)...
        );
    }

    template <char head, char... tail, typename F, typename... Args,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<F, separator_t<char>>::value == false, F>::type>
    std::basic_string<char> concat(F&& first, Args&&... rest) {
        return concat_intern<char>(
            get_separator<char, head, tail...>(), 
            std::forward<F>(first), 
            std::forward<Args>(rest)...
        );
    }

    template <const char* sep, typename F, typename... Args,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<F, separator_t<char>>::value == false, F>::type>
    std::basic_string<char> concat(F&& first, Args&&... rest) {
        return concat_intern<char>(
            sep, 
            std::forward<F>(first), 
            std::forward<Args>(rest)...
        );
    }

    template <typename CharT = char, typename F, typename... Args,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<F, separator_t<CharT>>::value == false, F>::type>
    std::basic_string<CharT> concat(F&& first, Args&&... rest) {
        return concat_intern<CharT>(
            (const CharT*)nullptr, 
            std::forward<F>(first), 
            std::forward<Args>(rest)...
        );
    }

    template <std::ostream& sep (std::ostream&), typename CharT = char, typename F, typename... Args,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<F, separator_t<CharT>>::value == false, F>::type>
    std::basic_string<CharT> concat(F&& first, Args&&... rest) {
        return concat_intern<CharT>(
            sep, 
            std::forward<F>(first), 
            std::forward<Args>(rest)...
        );
    }

}

#endif
```

- Does this code follow the common conventions?
- Do you think there is any way to improve this implementation in terms of efficiency, versatility or convenience?
- Do you think this could also benefit from new changes of C++14?

This would be sample of the client code:

```
std::cout << concat(1,2,3,4,5) << std::endl; // prints "12345"
```

But is really much more versatile than this, you can check more [here](https://github.com/theypsilon/concat).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I love it when new users ask such nice questions.

Comment: Small thing caught my eye: there's a typo of coma that should be comma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only advice I could offer is to use "modern" style traits that work nicely with the standard library through the usage of `std::integral_constant` and expression SFINAE.

For example, `has_const_iterator` can be rewritten like this:

```
template<typename...>
struct void_ {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename... Args>
using Void = typename void_<Args...>::type;

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct has_const_iterator : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_const_iterator<T, Void<typename T::const_iterator>> : public std::true_type {};
```

Now you get the benefit of `std::integral_constant` without having to redefine `::value`. It'll also work with tag dispatching that takes in `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` as parameters.

It's fairly uncommon to define traits as `constexpr` bool functions as well since this disallows the use of higher ordered meta functions, so I'd suggest moving those into their own traits like you did with `has_begin_end` and `has_const_iterator`.

On a final note, `has_begin_end` can be simplified immensely through the use of expression SFINAE as seen here:

```
struct has_begin_end_impl {
    template<typename T, typename B = decltype(std::declval<T&>().begin()),
                         typename E = decltype(std::declval<T&>().end())>
    static std::true_type test(int);
    template<typename...>
    static std::false_type test(...);
};

template<typename T>
struct has_begin_end : public decltype(has_begin_end_impl::test<T>(0)) {};
```

You can learn more about expression SFINAE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654067/what-is-expression-sfinae). As for the reason that there's `test(int)` and `test(...)`, that's for making the call `test(0)` unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I updated the code with your feedback in my repo. Do you know if is possible to use SFINAE to detect if a non-member free function is overloaded for a given class? (like std::begin)

Comment: @JoséManuel Yup. Just do the same expression SFINAE trick above, i.e. `decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))`.

Answer (score 3):

In all, this is a nice piece of work.  I have only a few minor points.

### Remove formal name `separarator` to quiet compiler warnings

When I compile the code with g++ with maximum warning levels, it complains that the parameter `separator` is not used in several functions.  Tracing this, it appears that a number of the `concat_intern_recursion` functions don't use it, so in my local copy, I've removed the formal parameter name `separator` (that is, I just leave `const S&`) from those calls and now get no warnings.

### Fix the spelling of `writer`

The word is spelled as `writter` throughout the code and documentation, but the correct spelling is `writer` with a single `t`.

### Consider if `constexpr` could be supported

I'm not sure if it would be possible to do, but the one thing I tried to do that it didn't support was usage like this:

```
constexpr std::string foo = concat(separator(" < "),1,3,5);
```

The compiler said it was due to the fact that `std::string` has a non-trivial destructor so perhaps it's out of your hands, but something to think about.

Comment: There is a way to do string concatenation with `constexpr` but this is only possible in C++14. `std::string` however wouldn't support it, you'd need a specific `constexpr string` type. It's fun to write, if anything

Comment: [Here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4121.pdf) is a proposal for a standard `constexpr` string class. You may want to use it as a base.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. constexpr would be nice, I'm also looking forward to string literals to pass the separator as a template argument in a nicer way.